# not able to set a list python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of usernames. Only usernames that aren't already in the text file should be added. Issue is that usernames that are already in there are getting added. I am printing the list to make sure it's working. Getting this error: Redeclared 'myList' defined above without usage.

```
myList = []

with open('list.txt', 'r') as file:
    myList = file.readlines()

print(myList)

username = input("Enter username: ")

if username not in myList:
    with open("list.txt", 'a+') as output:
        output.write(str(username) + "\n")
    print(f"Successfully added {username} to list")
else:
    print(f"{username} already exists in list")
```

Comment: Did you inspect the contents of `myList`? Did you compare them with the value of `username`? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Also `username` is already a string, you don't need to convert it to one

Comment: The code you provided works, and no errors raised. But the implementation is not correct, because your `myList` instance will contain usernames with `\n` character at the end. And this condition `if username not in myList` will be always true, even you have entered a username that is inside of the list.txt. I would recommend to use a good IDE, like PyCharm Community Edition and debug your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this line

`myList = file.readlines()` returning with `\n` every line

so change it to

`myList = [line.rstrip() for line in file.readlines()]`